# Prestashop: problema al añadir condicionales en archivo tpl (PHP & Smarty)

Tags: php, html, prestashop, smarty

Antes de nada, pedir disculpas por postear en inglés. El auto-localizador del navegador me jugó una mala pasada.

Actualmente estoy intentando introducir en el archivo de confirmación de pedido un código descuento variable que se muestre de forma condicional si se cumplen dos condiciones:

- El usuario tiene una cuenta
- El peso del pedido

Hasta ahora he probado el siguiente condicional en el archivo order-confirmation.tpl

```
{if ($order.shipping_weight >= 1.00) && ($logged)}
    <div class="5-percent-voucher">Voucher</div>
{elseif ($order.shipping_weight >= 2.00) && ($logged)}
    <div class="10-percent-voucher">Voucher</div>
{else}
{/if}
```

La buena noticia es que esto no rompe el sitio ni me devuelve un error 500, pero, por desgracia, tampoco consigo que funcione.

¿Sabría alguien decir qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido! Estás en el sitio de SO en español. Por favor, traduce la pregunta, de otro modo acabará eliminada.

Comment: Gracias por avisarme Roger! No me di cuenta. Ya está editada en castellano. Disculpa las molestias!!